# How to replace a matrix in an expression?

Tags: matrix, replacement

I have some code here

```
M = A = ConstantArray[0, {3, 2}];(*initialization*)
Q = ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}];
\[Beta] = ConstantArray[0, {2, 1}];
Table[{A[[i, j]] = Subscript[a, i, j], M[[i, j]] = Subscript[m, i, j]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 2}];
Table[\[Beta][[i, 1]] = Subscript[b, i], {i, 1, 2}];
Table[Q[[i, j]] = Subscript[q, i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
```

I want to replace the `A` with `MatrixPower[Q,2]`, but

```
A . \[Beta] + M . \[Beta] /. A -> MatrixPower[Q, 2]
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `A` is getting evaluated to the value you defined for it earlier, so before the replace can even get started, the symbol `A` is gone (both in the primary expression and also in the replacement rule.

You could just use a different symbol.

```
X . \[Beta] + M . \[Beta] /. X -> MatrixPower[Q, 2]
```

But if for some reason this expression must start with `A` in it, then you'll probably need to play some games with Hold:

```
ReleaseHold[Hold[A . \[Beta] + M . \[Beta]] /. HoldPattern[A] -> MatrixPower[Q, 2]]
```

For what it's worth,

```
MatrixPower[Q, 2] . \[Beta] + M . \[Beta]
```

generates an error message about threading things of incompatible dimensions. I haven't tried to debug/analyze your code.